# GZipStream and DeflateStream in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently migrating an ASP.NET MVC project to ASP.NET Core 3.1. I need to have same functionality in .Net core as well. But now I'm not able to use these methods. It gives error under `CompressionMode.Compress` like

> cannot convert from 'System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode' to 'System.IO.compression.compressionLevel

Also, I need to use response.Filter along with that, which also showing this error:

> HttpResponse does not contain definition for Filter.

I have placed below code inside a OnResultExecuting() method of a class that derives ActionFilterAttribute.

```
string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
//HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
HttpResponse response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
{   
    //..
    response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
}
else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
{
    //..
    response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
}
```

Is it possible to do in this class itself? Else is there any other methos to achieve this?

I moved the code to result filter like below:

```
namespace HTTPCompression.ActionFilters
{
public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpRequest request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];            
        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

        //HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        HttpResponse response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
        {             
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {                
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Do something after the result executes.
    }
}
}
```

Still having same issue as mentioned above.

Comment: The first error is most likely caused by the second: since `response.Filter` is undefined, the compiler doesn't know which constructor overload you're trying to call.

Comment: I suspect you need to use [a result filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#result-filters).

Comment: Best way is to use latest VS and then target the type of Core you want.  Then make sure you download the latest Core runtime version.  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1?force_isolation=true